# Unhide a div element using JavaScript with 'grace'?

Tags: javascript, html, styles, hidden

I have a hidden div. Through JavaScript, I unhidden the element. But I want to unravel the div tag with, like, 'grace', and not so automatic. I mean with style, is that possible with javascript?thanks

**HTML**

```
<input type="button" value="Unhide" onclick="unhide();"/>
<div class="readystate" id="readystate">
 <!-- something here -->
</div>
```

**css:**

```
.readystate{
visibilty: hidden;
}
```

**javascript:**

```
function unhide(){
   document.getElementById("readystate").style.visibility = "visible";
   document.getElementById("readystate").style.display=block;
}
```

Comment: You can use the javascript JQuery library to do this. you can do animations with it and just say ('$myDiv').show(); , which will gracefully show the div

Comment: Use CSS transitions for, well, transitions.

Comment: It should be noted that CSS transitions are CSS3, and not all transitions work well in all browsers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, gradually increase the DIV's opacity over several intervals until it's completely visible, like this:

```
function unhide() {
    var el = document.getElementById('readystate'),
        opac = 0,
        interval = setInterval(function () {
            opac += 0.1;
            if (opac >= 1) {
                clearInterval(interval);
                opac = 1;
            }
            el.style.opacity = opac;
        }, 100);
    el.style.opacity = 0;
    el.style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

If you want it to take longer, just increase the interval from 100, and vice versa. And if you want it smoother, decrease the amount of opacity added at each step from 0.1.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/M5KYD/1/)

Answer (score 1):

I seriously suggest you try jQuery.  It has a fantastic animation libarary that's incredibly easy to use.  You can download the library from Google or from jQuery.com (amongst other public sources):

- http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js
- http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js

So, to 'gracefully' show your div, first add jQuery to your page:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Then, you can create your function:

```
<script>
    function showMyDiv(){
        $('.readyState').show();  //this grabs all elements using the class ".readyState" and uses the "show" jQuery function
    }
</script>
```

Check out the documentation:   http://api.jquery.com/show/

Also, check out other jQuery functions like [addClass](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/), [removeClass](http://api.jquery.com/removeclass/), [css](http://api.jquery.com/css/), and other transition/animation functions like [slideDown](http://api.jquery.com/slidedown/), [slideUp](http://api.jquery.com/slideup/), and [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/).  And it's also very easy to add Javascipt events to HTML elements using jQuery.  The more you use it, the more you'll be hooked.